# How to convert virtual resources to a hash

Tags: puppet

I have a resource that takes ‘hash’ as an argumnent:

```
nginx::resource::map { ‘verions’:
  mappings => { hash of nginx upstreams here }
}
```

The problem is, the data for that hash is not available at the place, but all over the environment. So i came up with idea to use virtual resources at those places:

```
@upstream_entry { ‘name’: location => ‘location’ }
```

And then collect them at the place

```
Upstream_Entry <| |>
```

But that doesnt help much excepts it gathers data together. How can I convert those fake resources into a hash and feed it to nginx?

This is related to templates since all the nginx::resource::map does it creates a file with hash conents.

Comment: Why not use the resource collector with `nginx::resource::map`?

Comment: @MattSchuchard resource collector will only collect resources in one place, but would not return hash of references to them in any possible way. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of researching I came into a conclusion that this is, in fact, not possible.

I can, however, use `concat` module (with `concat::fragment`) to construct a configuration file from resources, by defining `concat::fragment` inside of them.

So that's why I came up into a [pull request](https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-nginx/pull/1161) for nginx module that solves my particular case: I simply had to abandon the idea of using hash as "upstreams source", but rather to use Puppet resources to define them, and them collect them together with `concat`.